# How to convert the string returned by JSON into Chinese? use C or C++

Tags: c++, json, character-encoding, chinese-locale, rapidjson

I write C++ code in vs2010.

How to convert the string returned by JSON into Chinese?

The JSON string returned from the server has this encoding

```
"name":"\u4e2d\u6587\u540d"
```

I cannot convert it to

```
string str="中文名";
```

I only can get :

```
string str="\u4e2d\u6587\u540d";
```

I do not know how to fix it. I use [rapidjson](http://rapidjson.org).

Please show me some code examples. Thank you.

Comment: A JSON decoder will do it for you if you're using it properly.

Comment: You can't store Chinese in a `std::string` unless it is encoded in UTF-8. While JSON is typically encoded in UTF-8, decoding it would not produce UTF-8 again. JSON escape sequences represent UTF-16 codeunits. If you want to store decoded JSON to a `std::string`, you would need to parse it to UTF-16 first (let a JSON library do that for you) and then re-encode the result to UTF-8

Comment: Can you provide a [mre]? (Otherwise, your question may be closed as off-topic.)

Comment: I use  rapidjson, but I cannot find decoded function which can parse the string "\u4e2d\u6587\u540d".

Comment: could you give a example?